# How to clean a bathtub

Tags: cleaning, bathroom, house-cleaning

I used cillit bang on my old plastic bathtub and if destroyed it. I know the best thing to do it to simply use soap.. but that seems to take forever. We have kids who have minor skin issues and have oilatum in the bath so it gets dirt rings regularly. Does anyone know of a none abrasive, or corrosive, fast and easy way to clean a bathtub?

Answer (score 1):

My go-to is Dawn dish soap and vinegar in a spray bottle. Spray, wipe with silicone scubby/sponge, and rinse. You'll see pages say you need to heat the vinegar. Maybe that helps, but I don't. The first time takes the longest, but once the tub is clean, it is quick.

My sister's go-to is use a "Mr. Clean Magic Eraser" and rinse. Generally, Magic Erasers are considered non-abrasive. If this method were as affordable as mine, I might her method, as it's quite a fast way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found any cleanser that effortlessly cuts through soap scum, so the principal effort is due to need to scrub.  And for scrubbing I have a "drill brush".  As the name implies, it is a brush that attaches to my cordless drill.  Several models for household work are sold on Amazon.  My tub looks like new with only a little effort.

Comment: Ooooh. Drill  brush!

Comment: Could you provide a link to drill brush?

Comment: There are several on Amazon.  I bought this one:  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B01MRLZ43B?aaxitk=tlq9QaZhwwfMVX2MKGaHfw&pd_rd_i=B01MRLZ43B&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=54dc821a-0937-4e6f-9da9-f8dd5443145d&pf_rd_s=desktop-sx-top-slot&pf_rd_t=301&pf_rd_i=drill+brush&hsa_cr_id=1312487820801&sb-ci-n=productDescription&sb-ci-v=Drillbrush%20Bathroom%20Surfaces%20Tub%2C%20Shower%2C%20Tile%20and%20Grout%20All%20Purpose%20Power%20Scrubber%20Cleaning%20Kit  Works quite well.